# Have a div to fill out the remaining height/width of a container when sharing it with another div?

Tags: html, css

Say I've got the following setup:

```
<div class="A parent">
    <div class="A a1"></div>
    <div class="A a2"></div>
    <div class="A a3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.A {
    width: 100%;
}

.parent {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px
}

.a1 {
    height: 100px;
 }

.a2 {
    height: 100px;
}

.a3 {
    // ??
}
```

Is there any way I can get `.a3` to fill out the remaining height of the parent div, *without* any content and *without* explicitly stating its height? This would be so useful for responsive design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple way of doing it.  Since you know your heights of the parent and the first two child elements, you can use absolute positioning for the third child block:

```css
.A {
    width: 100%;
}
.parent {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
}
.a1 {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: pink;
}
.a2 {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: beige;
}
.a3 {
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/WbRZn/

This uses CSS2 so it should be backwards compatible, probably back to IE5.

Comment: This an extremely nifty solution!

Comment: Indeed, this is a very useful trick, especially when you know heights and widths!

Comment: Useful if you know many things, like heights of preceding divs, and which one you explicitly want to set the `bottom` on, but what about organically, like @styke mentioned in the comments related to mine: "What if one of the elements, say the middle one, has no explicit height but gets its height from content?"

Comment: That is why flex was created! Otherwise, one would need JavaScript to compute the height of the middle box and so on.

Comment: You should probably check out the CSS3 [FlexBox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) concept, too. Thankfully, that's the future, so if you've got an opportunity to design for it, by all means do.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, since you have a hardcoded height to your parent container, you can set the height of `.a3` to 100%:

**CSS**

```
.parent {
  overflow: hidden; /** This will hide the overflow **/
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px
}

.a3 {
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[Codepen example.](http://cdpn.io/gxhcr)

**UPDATE with Flexbox solution**

Using `flexbox`, and defining a `flex-direction` of `column`, you can have your columns organically assume a height based on a parent container.

**CSS**

```
.parent {
  display: flex; /** Set display type **/
  flex-direction: column; /** Flexbox direction **/
  flex-wrap: nowrap; /** Each row should take up 100% of the width **/
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}


.a1, .a2, .a3 {
  flex-grow: 1; /** 1 per row **/
}

.a1 { background: green; } /** No more explicit heights, if you want **/
.a2 { background: red; }
.a3 { background: blue; }
```

Comment: Ah. What if one of the elements, say the middle one, has no explicit height but gets its height from content?

Comment: OK :) one sec, let me whip something up.

Comment: In the meantime, you should check out CSS Flexbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Comment: Sorry, I need it to fit the parent perfectly.

Comment: Updated with flexbox solution.

Comment: This is useful if you DON'T have explicit heights, and you can't make assumptions.

Comment: It looks like by default, the height is distributed evenly among the child elements.  It will be great when `display: flex` is widely supported.  Nicely done.

Comment: You might want to add a footnote about browser support (-moz prefix) and so on, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the look you were going for, you could always wrap the first two boxes with `.a3`, then set `height: 100%` on `a3`.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case OP's first comment on @kunalbhat's answer is an important requirement

> What if one of the elements, say the middle one, has no explicit height but
>   gets its height from its content?

you can use `display: table;` and `display: table-row;` like this:

**CSS:**

```
.A {
    width: 100%;
}
.parent {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    display: table;
}
.a1 {
    background-color: pink;
}
.a2 {
    background-color: beige;
}
.a3 {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}
```

Here's a <kbd>**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WbRZn/1/)**</kbd>, this should [work in and IE8+ and all other browsers](http://caniuse.com/css-table).