# How to let an element expand until its container reaches a boundary (with flex layout)?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

(following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098042/) and its helpful answer)

I'm trying to create container with a header and a footer, and a main content area which can grow/shrink as necessary. No sizes are known in advance. The whole thing should be allowed to grow vertically until the container hits a set limit using `max-height`.

Ideally, the header and footer height never change; the article grows only as high as it needs to display its contents, but is limited by the size of its container.

Can this be achieved with only CSS?

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Demo**

- working with a fixed container size: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yf6f/)
- same as above, interactive: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yf6f/1/)
- broken version using `max-height` instead of `height`: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yf6f/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <header>header 1<br>header 2<br>header 3</header>
    <article>content 1<br>content 2<br>content 3 ...</article>
    <footer>footer 1<br>footer 2<br>footer 3</footer>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    max-height: 300px; /* this makes the article content disappear */
}
article {
    flex: 2;
    overflow: auto;
    background: gold;
}
```

I've tried various values in the `flex:` property, including 0%, 100%, or main-size as the flex-basis, but couldn't get the result I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your are not using flexbox properly:

http://jsfiddle.net/7RB2h/1/

```
div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /* We set the direction as column */
    width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px; /* The max height you require */
}
article {
    flex-grow: 1; /* Article will then become flex */
    overflow: auto;
    background: gold;
}

/* (colors, not important) */
div { background: #eee; }
header { background: tomato; }
article { background: gold; }
footer { background: lightgreen; }
```

Comment: Please excuse my late reaction, I was on vacation. I agree that I'm probably not using flexbox correctly, but your example does not quite solve the problem. The header/footer areas get squished when they contain more than a single line: http://jsfiddle.net/7RB2h/2/