# CSS flex box with vertical content equal full screen distribution

Tags: css, flexbox

I am try to apply flex box to my layout, but i am bit lost on how to achieve the following. How would i achieve this so the 3 panel always take the full screen with 5% 90% and 5%.

Note: at the moment i have top and bottom position fixed, and javascript calculate the height with the middle panel but it's not ideal.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of : [Fill remaining vertical space with CSS using display:flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098042/fill-remaining-vertical-space-with-css-using-displayflex/25098486)

however:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: turquoise;
}
header {
 height:15%;
}

footer {
 height:5%;
}
main {
  flex:1;  
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header 15%
</header>
<main>
  main room left
</main>
<footer>
  footer 5%
</footer>
```

Comment: can you do px on the header and footer and content middle takes up the remaining.

Comment: @bluebill1049 ,yes, just play with my example. as long as main has flex:1; it will use whole space left avalaible. if not enough, use overflow or let the page grow taller. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYGbdw

Comment: Thank you mate this is great