# Stack 3 divs while bottom div height is adjusted automatically

Tags: html, css

I've got 3 divs.

```
<div class="top"> TOP </div>
<div class="middle"> MIDDLE </div>
<div class="bottom"> BOTTOM </div>

.top{
 position: fixed;
 top:0;
 width: 100%;
}
.bottom{
 position: fixed;
 bottom:0;
 width: 100%;
}
```

`middle` div contains a dynamic data. So I have enabled the scrollbar there.

```
.middle{
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

My question is, How can I stack the `middle` div and make the`bottom` adjusts its height automatically depending on the data in `top` and `middle` divs?

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: It is still not clear what you want. Are those 3 divs body sections? Are all with unknown heights? Should bottom be a sticky footer? Can you give us current styles for each block? Can you update this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/54cc01jy/)?

Comment: The div's have id's, but in the css code you are specifying classes?

Comment: Did it fixed your problem, though?

Comment: @skobaljic Thank you. The 3 divs should fit the screen height. `top` , `middle` div height is based on it's contents. All 3 divs should stick in their positions.

Comment: @Becky Could you post a plunkr of exactly what you are trying to show or what you currently have?

Comment: @MZeinstra No. it was a typo in my post. Thanks.

Comment: @EvanBechtol Please see my edit.

Comment: @Becky your post says that the bottom div has a scrollbar, is this a typo? Your picture shows the middle div with scrollbar.

Comment: @EvanBechtol - Thanks again. Yes that was a typo. I've altered it.

Comment: looks a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098042/fill-remaining-vertical-space-with-css-using-displayflex/2509848  demo http://jsfiddle.net/7yLFL/445/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the flex model is here to help you:

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin:auto;
  }
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  background:turquoise;
}
.middle {
  flex:1;
  overflow:auto;
  background:tomato;
  }
```

```html
<div class="top"> TOP any height</div>
<div class="middle"> MIDDLE i scroll if too tall </div>
<div class="bottom"> BOTTOM any height</div>
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/7yLFL/445/

Comment: You need to change overflow to overflow-y: auto     Also, you should use a max-height attribute most likely, otherwise the scroll never appears

Comment: @EvanBechtol can you set fiddles with issue you noticed ? , you understand this a 101 template based on flex value behavior ?

Comment: It wasn't scrolling in the snippet that you posted, I clicked the fiddle afterwards and see that it's correct ;) my mistake

Answer (score 2):

Flex model with no restrictions on any section height:

```css
html,
body {
 height: 100%;
}
body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 22px;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
}
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 width: 50%;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 float: left;
}
.top {
 background: none #59B2FF;
}
.middle {
 flex-grow: 100;
 overflow-y: auto;
 background: none #FFB800;
}
.bottom {
 align-self: flex-end;
 width: 100%;
 background: none #A1FFB5;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper wrapper1">
 <div class="top">top</div>
 <div class="middle">middle</div>
 <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper wrapper2">
 <div class="top">top</div>
 <div class="middle">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.?</div>
 <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

Also on **[Fiddle playground](https://jsfiddle.net/54cc01jy/2/)**.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an `.outer` div that is basically a container for `.top,  .middle,   .bottom`. You would also create a css class called `.inner` that has position absolute:

```
#CSS
.outer {
  #Can position however you want
}
.inner {
  position: relative;
}
.top {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.middle {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 100px;  //Optional; if you want to specify the maximum height this div can take
  width: 100%;
}
.bottom {
   width: 100%;
   bottom: 0
}
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner top"> TOP </div>
    <div class="inner middle"> MIDDLE </div>
    <div class="inner bottom"> BOTTOM </div>
</div>
```

Here is a plunker [**DEMO**](https://embed.plnkr.co/IRwJ5TvMkm6FWYSeU2lo/)

Answer (score 0):

Just put:

```
   .middle{
        position: relative;
        height: auto;
    }
```

Since, you have put position fixed for top container, so it won't move out of screen and will be stuck at the top while the other two divs will be scrollable under the top div.

Comment: What you want to keep the bottom as footer fixed? If so, then you can make the bottom div as position fixed too.

Comment: Thanks. Won't the content of `middle` run under `top` and `bottom`

Comment: Yes, it will in that case.