# Stretch columns in two columns layout with shared header using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using flexbox to create a two-columns layout with a header row.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 300px;
}

.header {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  border: 2px solid magenta;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.column1 {
  flex-basis: 150px;
  /* height: calc(100% - 50px); */
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.column2 {
  /* height: calc(100% - 70px); */
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='header'>it's a header</div>
  <div class='column1'>column 1</div>
  <div class='column2'>column 2</div>
</div>
```

Feel free to see the full example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6ph7b1yj/).

As you can see in the example there is a gap between columns and header. My aim is to stretch columns vertically to fill whole empty space in the container.
I can achieve it by setting `height` property like `calc(100% - <header-height>)`. Is it the correct way?

I just tried to use "flex" style and set `align-items: stretch` to the container and `align-self: stretch` to columns but without success. Did I probably miss something trying to implement it this way?

Comment: Why don't you just use grid instead of flexbox?

Comment: Since flexbox is a 1-dim. system, it is, there's nothing you can do about it. You can only optimize it with the use of CSS variables so that you don't have to change the height more than once.

Comment: @elena it's just a try to understand how flexbox does work :) Anyway, thanks for explanation in your answer

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36167253/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like shown below

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid magenta;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.body-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.column1 {
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.column2 {
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='header'>it's a header</div>
  <div class="body-container">
    <div class='column1'>column 1</div>
    <div class='column2'>column 2</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think specifying `flex-direction` as `column` is appropriate in this case.
The second row is itself a `flex` element with the `flex-direction: row`. You can fill the rest of the remaining space using `flex: 1`, which is equivalent to `flex-grow: 1`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 300px;
}

.header {
  border: 2px solid magenta;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.subcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
}

.column1 {
  flex-basis: 150px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.column2 {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='header'>it's a header</div>
  <div class="subcontainer">
    <div class='column1'>column 1</div>
    <div class='column2'>column 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```