# Flexbox body and main min-height

Tags: css, height, flexbox

https://jsfiddle.net/vz7cLmxy/

I'm trying to have the body to expand but the min-height does not work. I've read other related topics but can't get my head around it.

**CSS and html**

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  background: #eee;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menu {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 300px;
}

.main {
  background: #ccc;
  flex: 1;
}

.footer {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">Menu</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="main">Main</div>
</div>

<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

Expected result is that main is streched to fill the height if it's less than 100%.

Comment: looks very much alike : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098042/fill-remaining-vertical-space-with-css-using-displayflex/25098486

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `flex: 1` on the centered element:

```css
.Site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Site-content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color:#bbb;
}
```

```html
<body class="Site">
  <header>This is the header text ☺</header>
  <main class="Site-content">…</main>
  <footer>This is the footer text ☻</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! A combination with setting flex: 1 on .wrap (in my case) and having width: 100% on html (instead of min-height) did the trick!

Answer (score 7):

To get `min-height` with relative units working even in IE11 it needs just a tiny trick.

The nature of `min-height` is to overwrite the `height` when `height` is smaller then `min-height`. Very clear! But the pitfall is when `min-height` has a realitve unit (`%` or `vh`) and `height` is not set. Since it is relative it has no basis to relay on.

For all major browsers except Internet Explorer one possibility is to change the unit from `%` to `vh`:

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

For Internet Explorer it needs a `height` (will be overwritten from `min-height`):

```
body {
  height: 1px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

or to keep `%` the rules has to be applied to `html` too:

```
html, body {
  height: 1px;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

A cross browser solution for the OP needs `height: 1px` on `body` and of course `flex-grow: 1` for `.wrap` to let it grow faster then `menu` and `footer`:

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 1px; /* added */
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  background: #eee;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menu {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1; /* added */
}

.sidebar {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 300px;
}

.main {
  background: #ccc;
  flex: 1;
}

.footer {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">Menu</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    <div class="main">Main</div>
</div>

<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

Comment: The problem with `height: 1px` is that you lose the autoscaling functionality with content. So in real life the `min-height` can just as well be made `height`. Losing the autoscaling means the content will never make the element grow beyond the `min-height`, and thus rendering the property useless.

Comment: @GuidoBouman @kmgt I just had this problem, and setting `height` to `fit-content` instead of `1px` worked for me. It gave `height` a value that `min-height` could override, but kept the auto-scaling functionality you'd lose otherwise.

Comment: You'll guess it! IE don't like `fit-content`. [caniuse/fit-content](https://caniuse.com/#search=fit-content)