# How to use flexbox to fill remaining height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.site-main {
  height: calc(100% - 72px);
  display: flex;
}
.site-main > div {
  min-width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
}
.site-main > aside {
  min-width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: $darkest-blue-grey;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Title</h1>
</header>
<div class="site-main">
  <div></div>
  <aside></aside>
</div>
```

I have the `header` at a fixed `height` of `72px`.

I have given `.site-main div` a `width` of `85%`.

I have given  `.site-main aside` a `width` of `15%`.

What I want is for `.site-main div` and `.site-main aside` to be side by side, and have `.site-main` fill the remaining white space after the `header`.

And have `.site-main div` and `.site-main aside` fill `.site-main`'s height.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is the flexbox?

Comment: What about your css?

Comment: @Troyer I assume it would go on the `.site-main`

Comment: @LeviMurray I made this without `flex`, maybe it solves your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/LouzebxL/3/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098042/fill-remaining-vertical-space-with-css-using-displayflex/25098486 very similar :)

Comment: @GCyrillus Found that one too, though this had the extra flex row element so I decided to not vote for duplicate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `flex-direction: column` on `body` and `flex: 1` on `site-main`.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  height: 75px;
}
.site-main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
.site-main div {
  flex: 0 0 85%;
  background: lightblue;
}
aside {
  flex: 0 0 15%;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Title</h1>
</header>
<div class="site-main">
  <div></div>
  <aside></aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

For you who need to support IE11 (and 10), this one solves the *IE min-height* bug

<strike>*Note, for this to work on IE10, prefixed flexbox properties needs to be added*</strike>

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;        /* IE 10 */
  display: flex;               /* IE11/10 bug fix    */
}
.wrapper {
  -ms-flex: 1;                 /* IE 10 */
  flex: 1;                     /*  fill 100% width   */
  display: -ms-flexbox;        /* IE 10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;  /* IE 10 */
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
header {
  height: 72px;
}
.site-main {
  -ms-flex: 1;                 /* IE 10 */
  flex: 1;                     /*  fill 100% height  */
  display: -ms-flexbox;        /* IE 10 */
  display: flex;
}
.site-main > div {
  width: 85%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.site-main > aside {
  width: 15%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="site-main">
    <div></div>
    <aside></aside>
  </div>
</div>
```