# Flexbox Style Only Works When Manually Entered in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: css, flexbox, google-chrome-devtools, ag-grid

I am trying to get an ag-Grid to fill the vertical space in a panel on a page. If I put the style on the .HTML page like this:

```
<style>
.right_panel > div {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    height: 95%;
    flex-direction: column;
}
</style>
```

... or include it in the Javascript:

```
            $(".right_panel > div").css("display", "flex");
            $(".right_panel > div").css("flex-direction", "column");
            $(".right_panel > div").css("height", "95%");
            $(".right_panel > div").css("flex", "1");
```

... the styles will correctly show up in the Chrome CSS Debugger:

[image]

... but my ag-Grid is crushed down to zero height.

{image of a page with a grid that only has a navbar under which there's a lot of white space}

Disabling them and retyping them into the CSS Debugger verbatim:

[image]

... and the grid works fine

{image of a page with a grid that properly fills the page}

Is there something obvious (obviously) that I'm missing? I've read questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098042/fill-remaining-vertical-space-with-css-using-displayflex) to get the grid to fill the available vertical space. Why does this seemingly correct css only work when manually entered in the CSS debugger, and how do I fix it in my code?

*Heavily* edited HTML for the page:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
<div id="main-view" ui-view="" class="ng-scope">
  <div class="vbox ng-scope">
    <div class="vbox-grow page-sidebar ng-scope splitter_panel" split-v="splitterCtrl">
     <main class="hbox-grow right_panel" style="width: 1233px;">
        <div ui-view="" class="ng-scope"><div class="task page ng-scope">  <!-- THIS is the line with the CSS I'm editing -->
          <div class="task page ng-scope">
            <article class="page-content">
              <ui-view class="ng-scope">
                 <article class="page-content ng-scope" style="height: 100%; background-color: aliceblue; display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex: 1;">
                   <div id="gridContainer" style="height: 100%; background-color: yellow; flex-direction: column; flex: 1 1 0%; display: flex;">

                    <!-- THIS is the div that gets populated with the ag-grid -->
                    <div id="gridContent" style="width: 100%; background-color: hotpink; flex: 1; display: flex; flex-direction: column;" class="ag-fresh">
```

Comment: can we see the HTML also

Comment: I'm working on a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) right now... there's an enormous amount of HTML on each page...

Comment: Might be a [bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?can=1&q=flex+height). Can you repro in other browsers?

Comment: The application uses Web SQL. As such, it only works in Chrome for now.

Comment: I seem to remember something about ag-grid not working with flexbox in some GitHub issue. Not sure if it's relevant to your problem.

Comment: @BobKaufman "Web SQL was deprecated because standards are really important and turning Web SQL into a proper standard would have been prohibitively difficult". Read more here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_SQL_Database and here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220254/why-is-web-sql-database-deprecated

Comment: @BobKaufman Given the above I recommend to change technology ASAP.

Comment: When it comes to the `height` issue, what does the CSS look like for the `.right_panel` ? ... Also, if you use viewport units instead, does that work, e.g. like this: `height: 95vh;`

Comment: When do you run the javascript that puts in the CSS? if it isn't already in the onGridReady event, try putting it in there