# React Component Height

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-component

I have created a react component to be the home page on my react app. I am using react router to navigate through the components on my site. I am able to display the home page component under my nav bar, however the problem that I am having is that the home page component is not taking up the whole rest of the page. I want the component to take up the rest of the page other than the navbar.

This is my Home.js (home page component)

```
import React from 'react';
import './Home.css';

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <html>
            <body>
                <div class="home">
                    <h1>Home Page</h1>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}
```

This is my navbar

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Navbar() {
    return (
        <div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark py-0">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Planet Code</a>


  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>

        </div>
    )
}
```

This is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import About from './components/About';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './components/Home';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Navbar />
      <Router>
      <div>
        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

This is a screenshot of the site
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to expand the home portion of the page is to use a min-height of 100vh and subtract the height of the navbar using [CSS calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) ...

```
.home {min-height: calc(100vh - 80px);}
```

... where 80px is the height of your navbar.

You could also use Flex, and flex-grow: 1 as per [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098042/fill-remaining-vertical-space-with-css-using-displayflex).

As an aside, your HTML isn't semantic the way you've set it up, as your Navbar HTML is outside of the Home component `<html>` tag.

I'd move the 
`<html><body></body></html>` tags into your App component, allowing Nav and Home to sit correctly in the html of the app.