# Ensure that the footer is on bottom of the page if the page has a short height

Tags: html, css, footer

I would like to have a `footer`:

- at the bottom of the page, even if the `main-container` is very short in height, e.g. only 300px high. In this case a big vertical margin should be added.
  Probably of something like `height(viewport) - height(main-container) - height(header)`
- in the normal flow of the body, after `<div id="main-container">`, so I don't want to place it with `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`.
- if the `main-container` is big (e.g. 1 page or more), then only a few margin should be added between `main-container` and `footer` (to the contrary of bullet point 1.)

**How to do this?**

```css
#header { background-color: yellow; }
#main-container { background-color: red; }
#footer { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="main-container">
Hello<br>
World
</div>
<div id="footer">
Bye-bye. <-- this should be on bottom even if main-container has only 2 lines
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS to make HTML page footer stay at bottom of the page with a minimum height, but not overlap the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643879/css-to-make-html-page-footer-stay-at-bottom-of-the-page-with-a-minimum-height-b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**actually , a very possible duplicate of [Fill remaining vertical space with CSS using display:flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098042/fill-remaining-vertical-space-with-css-using-displayflex/25098486)**

You may take a look at flex and flex-grow.

```css
body {
display:flex;
flex-flow:column;
min-height:100vh;
margin:0;
}
#main-container {
flex:1;
}
#footer {}


/* = */
#header { background-color: yellow; }
#main-container { background-color: red; }
#footer { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="main-container" contentEditable>
Hello<br>
World
</div>
<div id="footer">
Bye-bye.
</div>
```

usefull link  :  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Perfect! I added `contentEditable` to see what happens if the main container grows in height.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```css
#footer {  position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%; height: 2rem; }
#main-container { padding-bottom: 2rem; }
```

```html
<div id="main-container" contentEditable>
Hello<br>
World
</div>
<div id="footer">
Bye-bye.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work if main-container grows in height: try, you will see an overlap.

Comment: Ah I see, will test more the next time!