# Css make child div 100% height and scrollable if necessary

Tags: html, css

Consider the following stacked divs:

```css
.page {
  height: 100%;
}

.top {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.bottom {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.options {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="top">
    <h1>TOP</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <h1>Options Menu</h1>
    <div class="options">
      <h1>Option 1</h1>
      <h1>Option 2</h1>
      <h1>Option 3</h1>
      <h1>Option 4</h1>
      <h1>Option 5</h1>
      <h1>Option 6</h1>
      <h1>Option 7</h1>
      <h1>Option 8</h1>
      <h1>Option 9</h1>
      <h1>Option 10</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I change it to allow only the options to scroll, not the page?

Comment: second snippet from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098486/8620333

Answer (score 0):

To activate scroll a height value is needed for the list in your case the `options` class doesn't have the height defined so define a `height`(as per your need) to the `options` class.

```css
.page {
  height: 100%;
}

.top {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.bottom {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.options {
  overflow: scroll;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="top">
    <h1>TOP</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <h1>Options</h1>
    <div class="options">
      <h1>Option 1</h1>
      <h1>Option 2</h1>
      <h1>Option 3</h1>
      <h1>Option 4</h1>
      <h1>Option 5</h1>
      <h1>Option 6</h1>
      <h1>Option 7</h1>
      <h1>Option 8</h1>
      <h1>Option 9</h1>
      <h1>Option 10</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No. Height of options class must be as tall as possible, that's why I've used 100%. I don't want it to be fixed at 200px. That's why I've posted que question....

Answer (score 0):

When you have more than one sibling div with `height:100%`, they each take up 100% of the height of the parent div, basically doubling the parent div's height:

```css
html,body{height:100%;margin:0}
h1{margin:0}

.page {
  height: 100%;
}

.top {
  background-color: red;
}

.bottom {
  height: 80%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.options {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="top">
    <h1>TOP</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <h1>Options Menu</h1>
    <div class="options">
      <h1>Option 1</h1>
      <h1>Option 2</h1>
      <h1>Option 3</h1>
      <h1>Option 4</h1>
      <h1>Option 5</h1>
      <h1>Option 6</h1>
      <h1>Option 7</h1>
      <h1>Option 8</h1>
      <h1>Option 9</h1>
      <h1>Option 10</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good explanation... But how about the solution? I want the last div to fill the remaining height...

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set a max-height on the container for the scroll to trigger, Im adding an example here:

```css
.page {
  height: 10vh;
  
}

.top {
  background-color: red;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: grey;
}

.options {
  height: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: green;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="top">
    <h1>TOP</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <h1>Options Menu</h1>
    <div class="options">
      <h1>Option 1</h1>
      <h1>Option 2</h1>
      <h1>Option 3</h1>
      <h1>Option 4</h1>
      <h1>Option 5</h1>
      <h1>Option 6</h1>
      <h1>Option 7</h1>
      <h1>Option 8</h1>
      <h1>Option 9</h1>
      <h1>Option 10</h1>
      <h1>Option 11</h1>
      <h1>Option 12</h1>
      <h1>Option 13</h1>
      <h1>Option 14</h1>
      <h1>Option 15</h1>
      <h1>Option 16</h1>
      <h1>Option 17</h1>
      <h1>Option 18</h1>
      <h1>Option 19</h1>
      <h1>Option 20</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for!