# CSS layout issue with Firefox

Tags: html, css, layout

In an existing project I have the layout working in all the browsers except Firefox, and before I go ahead and rip it all up, I was wondering if there was a quick fix.

Given the following: https://jsfiddle.net/2m690rux/3

The scrollable area in the middle is not scrolling because Firefox will not scroll content unless it knows the actual hight in pixels, and you cannot say `height:100%` (as the sample does) but this does work in Chrome and others.

I have been able to calculate and set the height of the scroll area by removing the content, measuring the `.height()` and then put the content back. Although this works... it is painful and requires very many changes to code.

Most of you are probably going to suggest using some complicated arrangements of DIVs and not tables, getting them to behave the same through some of the most mind boggling CSS hacks and tricks... so, I was wondering if anyone knows the simplest solution, considering that this sample is only a small example of a much much bigger code set... changes now will have huge ramifications.

```css
body, html{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body{
  position: static;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.theTable{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.topSection{
  height: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.midSection{
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 5px;
}
.scrollContainer{
  height: 100%; /* <-- This is a problem for Firefox */
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.bottomSection{
  height: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
 <table class=theTable cellspacing=5 cellpadding=2>
  <tr>
   <td class="topSection">
    <div>n items of unknow height (no scroll)</div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class=midSection>
    <div class=scrollContainer>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class=bottomSection>
     <div>n items of unknow height (no scroll)</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D I didn't even realise this site had a code snippet tool, i have updated it.

Comment: So you want the mid section to be scrollable if there is a lot of content?

Comment: @Sam Correct - if viewed in Chrome and Firefox as the sample is now, you can see the two browsers behaving different.

Comment: Do you really need a table here ? , because for such a layout flex or grid do the job really well.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I know, I know... tables right? is it really such a problem? I mean are tables not just elements on a page with a predefined display. If this is truly not possible with tables, i guess ill have to change it... i'm really reluctant tho and don't know what new can of worms im opening up.

Comment: Well, I'd always go with divs! The real can of worms are the tables ;-) They are rigid and hard to manipulate if you want something special from them. And responsive design is a nightmare with tables. So I would replace them by divs whenever and wherever possible.

Comment: table seems a problem with FF, position:relative/absolute might help : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MWKJEzK  . If your table is here only for a layout purpose, drop it, use flex or grid , you'll find these much more usefull later ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus That's exactly what im looking for... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

position might help : *(if table is not needed  , you may inspire yourself from [Fill remaining vertical space with CSS using display:flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098042/fill-remaining-vertical-space-with-css-using-displayflex/25098486#25098486) )*

```css
body, html{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body{
  position: static;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.theTable{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.topSection{
  height: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.midSection{
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 5px;
  position:relative;
}
.scrollContainer{
  height: 100%; /* <-- This is a problem for Firefox */
  overflow-y: auto;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
}
.bottomSection{
  height: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
 <table class=theTable cellspacing=5 cellpadding=2>
  <tr>
   <td class="topSection">
    <div>n items of unknow height (no scroll)</div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class=midSection>
    <div class=scrollContainer>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
     <div>Item n of x</div>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class=bottomSection>
     <div>n items of unknow height (no scroll)</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a great idea!

Comment: Now I just need to get it to be padded a bit.

Comment: @Conrad inside the scrolling div : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MWKJEzK ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I see you used calc(), nice thanks. I have already implemented the changes. This is the result: https://www.innovateasterisk.com/phone/

Answer (score 0):

While I don't understand why your code should work in other browsers, the issue is quite simple to solve. If you set `height: 100%` the respective div will have the total height of it's content, so there is nothing to scroll!

If you want your cell to be scrollable, you have to set a `max-height` to the `scrollContainer`. Let´s say for example the `max-height` was `200px`, then the result would be [this](https://jsfiddle.net/96m145fn/4/).

Your `overflow-y: auto;` is correct, but it needs to know *when* the content overflows. With a height of 100% there is no content overflowing.

Comment: This doesn't fix his issue in any form.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. The "when" in when it must scroll is when the the content (heigh) of scrollContainer exceeds its parent (this has an unknown height)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question/statement, but you *need* to define a hight so that the content can exceed the parent container. As your parent container has no fixed height, either I don't see how this should work.

Comment: @Sam In all other browsers except Firefox, scroll bars appear when the rows are increased. As I mentioned, I am able to set the height statically with a javascript, but am looking for a CSS only solution.