# Fit div to Remaining Space of Vertically-Centred Parent

Tags: html, css

With the following code, I'm trying to make it so that the 'scroll' div occupies exactly the remaining space of the 'frame' div's height (ending at its padding boundary).

I would like to avoid a situation where the height of the scroll div is hardcoded, as it should scale with its parent (according to the window height).

I haven't been able to figure out a CSS-based solution, and would much appreciate suggestions.

```css
:root {
    --dlgMW: 0px; --dlgW: 0px;
    --dlgMH: 0px; --dlgH: 0px;
}

html, body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.editor {
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;

    background-color: #393939;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dialog.show {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.dialog {
    color: #CCC;
}

.dialog > .window {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

    min-width: var(--dlgMW);
    width: var(--dlgW);
    min-height: var(--dlgMH);
    height: var(--dlgH);

    border-radius: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dialog > .window > .frame {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/ /* FIXME - Should not be needed */
}

.dialog > .window > .frame > .body {
    position: relative;
    height: 80%;
}

.dialog .content > .scroll {
    overflow-y: auto; /* FIXME Scroll should be visible when div would exceed frame's padding */
}

li.series {
    display: block;
    height: 3em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}

li.series:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en_US" dir="LTR" style="--dlgMW:500px; --dlgW:50%; --dlgMH:0px; --dlgH:80%;">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="editor">
            <div class="dialog show">
                <div class="window">
                    <div class="frame">
                        <div class="body">
                            <div class="content">
                                <h2>Switch Series</h2>
                                <div class="scroll">
                                    <ol id="series_list">
                                        <li class="series">
                                            <span class="series_title">Create New Series</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="series">
                                            <span class="series_title">Main Timeline</span>
                                        </li>

                                        <!-- For testing scroll behavior -->
                                        <li class="series">
                                            <span class="series_title">Custom series 1</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="series">
                                            <span class="series_title">Custom series 2</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="series">
                                            <span class="series_title">Custom series 3</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="series">
                                            <span class="series_title">Custom series 4</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="series">
                                            <span class="series_title">Custom series 5</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="series">
                                            <span class="series_title">Custom series 6</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="series">
                                            <span class="series_title">Custom series 7</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="series">
                                            <span class="series_title">Custom series 8</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="series">
                                            <span class="series_title">Custom series 9</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="series">
                                            <span class="series_title">Custom series 10</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="series">
                                            <span class="series_title">Custom series 11</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="series">
                                            <span class="series_title">Custom series 12</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="series">
                                            <span class="series_title">Custom series 13</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="series">
                                            <span class="series_title">Custom series 14</span>
                                        </li>
                                    </ol>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why so many elements and `position/transform`, anyway, going down to `.content`, where it seems to happen, you may use  the flex model :

```css
:root {
  --dlgMW: 0px;
  --dlgW: 0px;
  --dlgMH: 0px;
  --dlgH: 0px;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.editor {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #393939;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dialog.show {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.dialog {
  color: #CCC;
}

.dialog>.window {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  min-width: var(--dlgMW);
  width: var(--dlgW);
  min-height: var(--dlgMH);
  height: var(--dlgH);
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dialog>.window>.frame {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1vh;
  height: 100%;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  /* FIXME - Should not be needed */
}

.dialog>.window>.frame>.body {
  position: relative;
  height: 80%;
}
/*---------------*/
/* -------update-*/
/*---------------*/
.dialog .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
/*---------------*/
/* ---end-update-*/
/*---------------*/

.dialog .content>.scroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* FIXME Scroll should be visible when div would exceed frame's padding */
}

li.series {
  display: block;
  height: 3em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}

li.series:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en_US" dir="LTR" style="--dlgMW:500px; --dlgW:50%; --dlgMH:0px; --dlgH:80%;">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="editor">
    <div class="dialog show">
      <div class="window">
        <div class="frame">
          <div class="body">
            <div class="content">
              <h2>Switch Series</h2>
              <div class="scroll">
                <ol id="series_list">
                  <li class="series">
                    <span class="series_title">Create New Series</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="series">
                    <span class="series_title">Main Timeline</span>
                  </li>

                  <!-- For testing scroll behavior -->
                  <li class="series">
                    <span class="series_title">Custom series 1</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="series">
                    <span class="series_title">Custom series 2</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="series">
                    <span class="series_title">Custom series 3</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="series">
                    <span class="series_title">Custom series 4</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="series">
                    <span class="series_title">Custom series 5</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="series">
                    <span class="series_title">Custom series 6</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="series">
                    <span class="series_title">Custom series 7</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="series">
                    <span class="series_title">Custom series 8</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="series">
                    <span class="series_title">Custom series 9</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="series">
                    <span class="series_title">Custom series 10</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="series">
                    <span class="series_title">Custom series 11</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="series">
                    <span class="series_title">Custom series 12</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="series">
                    <span class="series_title">Custom series 13</span>
                  </li>
                  <li class="series">
                    <span class="series_title">Custom series 14</span>
                  </li>
                </ol>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If it's not a duplicate of [Fill remaining vertical space with CSS using display:flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098042/fill-remaining-vertical-space-with-css-using-displayflex/25098486#25098486) , it is very similar :)

Comment: Hmm, thanks! Needed to adjust the height % a little to get the expected fit, but this works perfectly!