# CSS Layout: Mobile, Vertical Layout, Header (fixed height), Footer (fixed height). How to fill remaining space with img, constrained on height & width

Tags: html, css, image, layout, flexbox

Layout: Mobile, Vertical Layout, Header (fixed height), Footer (fixed height). How to fill remaining space with img, constrained on height & width

This is a very common layout for me on iOS. Trying to understand how to do it in CSS.

Here's what I'm trying:

Using flexbox with flex-direction column
Setting height of header and footer (or can be done with flex-basis)
flex-shrink: 0 for header and footer so they don't shrink
flex-shrink: 1 on the image container so it shrinks if needed
Setting max-width and max-height to 100% on image
object-fit: scale-down so it keeps the aspect ratio of the image (this means there will be horizontal bars or vertical bars)

Issue: the image shrinks to fit the width, but should shrink even more than that to fit the available vertical space

**HTML**

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='header'>
    Header
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='image-container'>
      <img class="cat" src="https://jngnposwzs-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Transparent-OrangeWhiteCat-764x1024.png"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='footer'>
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  background-color: #aaa;
  height: 400px;
  width: 175px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.box {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box1 {
  height: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.box2 {
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.cat {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: scale-down;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}

.box3 {
  height: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

https://codepen.io/jeffrey-robert/pen/yLbNVZp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `object-fit`, then the trick is to set to `img` :`height:0;min-height:100%;width:100%` and it should fill the flex child boxe, the child boxe **will require** `flex-grow:1;` **too** to [fill the remaing space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098042/fill-remaining-vertical-space-with-css-using-displayflex/25098486#25098486).

```css
.container {
  background-color: #aaa555;
  height: 400px;
  width: 175px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.box {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box1 {
  height: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.box2 {
  flex:1 1 auto;
}

.cat {
  width: 100%;
  height:0;
  min-height:100%;
  object-fit: scale-down;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}

.box3 {
  height: 100px;
  flex-shrink:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="box box2">
    <img class="cat" src="https://jngnposwzs-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Transparent-OrangeWhiteCat-764x1024.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="box box3">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much, you have no idea how many people this stumped haha! I never would have guessed height:0 min-height:100%

Comment: @JeffHanna , also flex-grow is needed here, then height/min-height can work ;)