# Scrollable full height div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I achieve a full height page app with a div that takes up remaining height under banner and uses scroll for the remainder.

The middle div is the one I need to scroll, as shown in this fiddle.

**[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ftarnLm/4/)**

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  background: gold;
  overflow: scroll;
  flex: 1;
}

.left {
  background: tomato;
}

.right {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    header banner
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="left">
      should always fill remaining height (Works)
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      main content: fills remaining space then overflows with scrollbar (doesnt work)<br> x
      <br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br> x
      <br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>

    </div>
    <div class="right">
      should always fill remaining height (Works)
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Much appreciated

Comment: Try to use `max-height`, `vh max-height`, and `overflow`, `.needToScroll { height: 100%; max-height: 100vh; overflow: auto;}`

Comment: In your `.content` block, adding `max-height: calc(100vh - 20px)` worked for me.  Also changed `overflow: auto;` since it looks better to me.  The 20px was for the header.

Comment: @user2740650 Thanks! My actual header (not the minimal jsfiddle reproduction) doesn't have a specified height. Do you have any ideas for how to do it when the height is unknown? Thanks

Comment: `html { height: 100%; }` is an useless statement. `height: 100%` means to occupy 100% of the aprent height. However this require that the parent has a defined height. Not a calculated height to fit the content. And right there is the issue, `html` has no parent element. Unless you give it a specific height, it will calculate the height to fit-content

Comment: Without hard-coding the header height, I'm not sure how with pure CSS.  This might help: http://jsfiddle.net/7yLFL/445/ (from a comment at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098486).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the header's height is set with CSS, you can set `.content` to take up the full height of the viewport (`100vh`) minus the height of the header using the `calc` function.

```css
.header {
  height: 20px;
}

.content {
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}
```

If the header's height can change depending on its contents, you can use javascript to set `.content`'s height on page load and resize.

```js
function setContentHeight() {
  let header = document.querySelectorAll('.header')[0];
  let content = document.querySelectorAll('.content')[0];
  if (header && content) {
    content.style.setProperty('height', 'calc(100vh - ' + header.offsetHeight + 'px)');
  }
}

document.addEventListener('ready', function() {
    setContentHeight();
    window.addEventListener('resize', setContentHeight);
});
```