# flex 1 won't fill available space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why won't flex 1 fill available space?

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px rgb(0 0 0 / 8%);
    border-radius: 45px;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.sub-container-one {
  font-size: 100px;
}

.sub-sub-container-two {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    /* this apparently should work but it doesn't */
      flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sub-container-one">
    ftftftftftftf
  </div>
  <div class="sub-container-two">
    <div class="sub-sub-container-two">
      ghghghghghghghghghghghg
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fill remaining vertical space with CSS using display:flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098042/fill-remaining-vertical-space-with-css-using-displayflex)

> flex: 1;  /* 1 and it will fill whole space left if no flex value are set to other children*/

There are no other children in the div.

Why can't I center `sub-sub-container-two` ?

I found this question: [Flexbox: center horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically)

It suggests to use a fix height but I can't do this because it needs to support multiple entries. How can I make flex 1 fill available space?

Comment: What to do mean by "fill available space"? Which space you want to fill with which container?

Answer (score 0):

Your flex children are `.sub-container-one` and `.sub-container-two`, not `.sub-sub-container-two`, so all your settings for `.sub-sub-container-two` should be applied to `.sub-container-two`. And horizontal centering is done with `justify-content`, BTW (not with  `align-items`)

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px rgb(0 0 0 / 8%);
    border-radius: 45px;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.sub-container-one {
  font-size: 100px;
}

.sub-container-two {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sub-container-one">
    ftftftftftftf
  </div>
  <div class="sub-container-two">
    <div class="sub-sub-container-two">
      ghghghghghghghghghghghg
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note that your container settings `align-items: flex-start;` and `justify-content: space-between;` have no effect if you allow the items to grow and fill the available width.