# Forcing the inner flex-box to be scrollable with a banner occupying the whole viewport height

Tags: html, css

I have a page that has a banner on the top. Under the banner, I would like to add a section with its own header/body/footer. The header is meant to be immediately below the banner and the footer always visible at the bottom of the page. The banner and the header should always be visible too. The body should occupy the rest of the viewport space.

Here is some html/css that demonstrates my issue:

````css
```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.root {
    height: 100vh;
    display: block;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
    height: 50px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 0;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    height: 100%;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    min-height: 0;
}

.header {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.header {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```
````

````html
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="root">
            <div class="top">Top</div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header">Header</div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="footer">Footer</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```
````

The snippet above manages to make the `content` div scrollable but also the whole document is scrollable (ie you cannot see the `top` div and the `footer` div at the same time).

I can fix this in this example by changing the `container` height to `calc(100vh - 50px)` (the height of the parent minus the height of the `top` div.

Is it possible to get the same result without having to hard-code anything in the height of `container`? ie, is there another way to force `container` to use only the remaining space and handle the shrinking internally using the only degree of freedom it has (which is the overflow on the `content` div)?

This has been marked as a duplicate of [Fill remaining vertical space with CSS using display:flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098042/fill-remaining-vertical-space-with-css-using-displayflex) . At first, it seems related and the 'full-screen' version of the accepted answer sound like the answer to this question however that is not the case; if I add a banner before the `section` in the question's answer, the whole document overflows by the height of the banner.

Comment: root and container can be removed to simplify https://jsfiddle.net/d5yb2v9g/ Else, you need to stretch container via flex-grow , not height https://jsfiddle.net/d5yb2v9g/1/