# Css Flex Direction Column align items space between

Tags: css, html-table, flexbox, dompdf

I am using  inline css to generate `dompdf`. With dompdf absolute does not work.

I want `col2` to show bottom of `td`. I tried `rowspan` I faced another issue `get_cellmap null`

I cannot use fixed height in `px` to `div(flex)` the `div.green` is variable.

col2 is a single `power by` that should be align at the bottom of `td`

How i can grow `div.col2` column enter remaining `td` space?

This looks duplicate to [Fill remaining vertical space with CSS using display:flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098042/fill-remaining-vertical-space-with-css-using-displayflex)

But here I am not filling the screen space Instead I need to stretch inside a table row.

```html
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
  <td style="width:70%">
    <div style="height:300px;background-color:green;">
    
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
  <div style="display:flex:flex-direction:column;align-items:stretch">
  
  
  <div class="col1">
    Top col
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
     power by
    </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/4y8foj9s/4/)

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if this is what you meant but here's a fix to show green col and top col aside of each other while the col2 is at the bottom:

```html
      <table style="width:100%">
    <tr  style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;align-items:stretch">
      <td style="width:70%">
         <div  style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;align-items:stretch">
        <div style="height:300px;background-color:green;width:80%">
        </div>
     <div class="col1">
        Top col
        </div></div>
      </td>
      <td>
      <div>
        <div style="" class="col2">
         power by
        </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

if that wasn't your intention please explain more.

Comment: Not in a new Row

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are requiring. Just add `height: 100%` to the right side containing div and then flex your child elements as required.

```css
.right {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col1 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: pink;
}

.col2 {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:70%">
      <div style="height:170px;background-color:green;">

      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="height:170px;">
      <div class="right">
        <div class="col1">
          Top col
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
          power by
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```